# Can you imply something ironic?

Tags: philosophy-of-language

Obviously you can imply something in an ironic phrase, but can you imply something ironic? Can the irony be left unsaid, and still be irony?

If so, is that verbal irony, or some other sort?

Comment: i can allude to socrates' irony, and so imply it, i guess? but is that an instance or irony, rather than just allusion? what about new critical irony, does it exist outside poetry?

Comment: If someone is arguing that black swans do not exist in front of a lake with a black swan on it, all you have to do for irony is nod at it, perhaps with a smirk. Anything a speech act can accomplish can, in principle, be accomplished by non-verbal means.

Answer (score 2):

A raised eyebrow is usually sufficient to imply irony. Irony is little more than a gesture at an implicit internal contradiction: a way of pointing out that expected outcomes and actual outcomes are markedly different. We don't really need words to express it — all we need to do is hold the dichotomy up so it's visible — but words can really refine the point.